# Get first name in an array of key-value pairs in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exchange-2013

While trying to write some maintenance scripts for our Exchange 2013 deployment, one of the ones I need is a script that will determine which server a database is currently active on, versus which one it should be active on.

Easy enough, except that I've run into a syntax I've not seen before, and can't figure out how to get the data I need from this. When I run the command `Get-MailboxDatabase Database1 | Select ActivationPreference`, the output I get looks like this:

```
{[Server1, 1], [Server2, 2]}
```

Now, I know what this *means* (Server1 is the preferred server to host the active copy of this database), but for my script I need to be able to extract that data -- and I can't figure that out. Array access can easily get me the first pair (`[Server1, 1]`), which is a `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`, but I'm a relative newbie to PowerShell and even to .NET in general and can't figure out what this means or how to get the information I need out of it.

What commands/methods/operators/etc exist that can extract the key in a key-value pair like this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, turns out this is dead simple. Don't know why I didn't try it sooner, but I piped one of these KeyValuePair objects into `Format-List`, and got the following output:

```
Key   : Server1
Value : 1
```

So, it's as simple as addressing the object's Key parameter to find that value in my script.